# Vue2 append component to compile bundle and access store data

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex

I hope I'm asking this right. I have a compiled Vue application and I would like to append components outside the compile code which would be my core code. I don't want nobody to touch the core code but they can build components and access store data inside the vue component. How can this be achieve?

1. Append component to the compile vue application
2. Access the vuex store inside the component

HTML index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>chatbot</title>
    <script src=https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es6-promise@4/dist/es6-promise.auto.js></script>
    <link href=/static/css/build.css rel=stylesheet>

</head>

<body>
    <div id=app></div>

    <script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/manifest.js></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/vendor.js></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/build.js></script>

</body>

</html>
```

HelloWorld.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <h2>Essential Links</h2>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
h1, h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
a {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you'd like allow normal user to access the store state, but doesn't allow them to modify it.

**Solution 1:**

Probably you will like to use `$refs` then call the methods of that component to access the data (or $store.state)

**Solution 2:**

using custom event like [Vue Guide on Component Comunications](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Emitting-a-Value-With-an-Event).

The codes will be like below:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false

let componentOptions = {

  template: `<div>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <h2>Essential Links</h2>
    <button @click="changeData()">Click me!!!</button>
  </div>
</div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      msg: 'Test'
    }
  },
  computed: {
    computedMsg: function () {
      return 'computed: ' + this.msg
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getData: function () {
      return this.computedMsg
    },
    changeData: function () {
      this.msg += '@'
      this.$emit('mymessage', 'computed: ' + this.msg)
    }
  }
}

Vue.component('child', componentOptions)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        childMsg1: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App',
        childMsg2: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
      }
  },
  methods:{
    getChildData: function () {
      this.childMsg1 = this.$refs.test.getData()
    },
    getDataChangeForChild: function (data) {
      this.childMsg2 = data
    }
  }
})

let childBuilder = Vue.extend(componentOptions)
let yourChild = new childBuilder()
yourChild.$mount('#your-app')
function getData() {
  document.getElementById('your-app-data').innerText = yourChild.getData()
}
```

```css
.hello {
  background-color:gray
}
span {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<h2>Case 1</h2>
  <button @click="getChildData()">Get Child Data</button>
  <p>Solution 1: {{childMsg1}}</p>
  <p>Solution 2: {{childMsg2}}</p>
  <child ref="test" v-on:mymessage="getDataChangeForChild"></child>
</div>
<h3 onclick="getData()">Case 2 (Click me to see the latest data): 
  <span id="your-app-data"></span>
</h3>
<div id="your-app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Sphinx but I think what I needed was 1# How to load a vue file into my html page if that is possible and 2# How to access the vuex data inside the app so that I can use the same data inside the vue file I'm trying to import inside the html page. I may need to repost my question.

Comment: @ifelse, probably case 2 is what you need.

Comment: I'm trying to see how exactly how you load the vue file into the html. I see you're using #your-app to append but how does this work?

Comment: Another thing I have compiled code that renders into the #app so the code/components I place inside the <div id="app"></div> doesn't work

Comment: @ifelse I don't understand, what is the compiled code? how you compile it?

Comment: npm run build .

Comment: I'm trying to add components on the fly outside the app and append to the DOM. So I would also need to access the vuex store data